# Aggregate the values in a raster that lie within a given distance from a given point (i.e. a circle)

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster file `nightlights` that maps nighttime luminosity from satellite imagery (300MB compressed data available [here](http://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/data/web_data/v4composites/F182013.v4.tar)). It takes longitude-latitude inputs for extraction, e.g. `extract(nightlights, data.frame(long, lat)` for long-lat inputs.

Given `point <- (long, lat)`, I want to be able to aggregate all values that lie within, say, 5 miles of `point` and calculate an average luminosity, ignoring NAs.

The raster package comes with [an `aggregate` method](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/aggregate) that performs this function, but only for rectangles rather than spherical circles.

Comment: Basically you want to process it with a circular kernel, and query the resulting image. Maybe something like [this](http://www.samuelbosch.com/2014/02/creating-kernel-density-estimate-map-in.html)? (I was supposing that you're going to make a lot of such queries - but maybe that's not the case..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the buffer argument for that:

```
e <- extract(nightlights, cbind(long, lat), buffer=10)
```